# Connect python with NORD VPN

Tags: python, vpn, os.system

Beneath you see code to connect Python with NORD VPN but it doesn't work at the moment.
The program get always message access refused.
Thanks!

...

```
import os
import time
import requests

ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print(f"\nWith Requests\nIp:\t{ip}")

server = "C:\\Program Files\\NordVPN> nordvpn -c"
os.system(server)
time.sleep(10)

ip = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
print(f"\nWith Requests\nIp:\t{ip}")
```

...

Comment: `server = "'C:\\Program Files\\NordVPN\\nordvpn' -c"`

Comment: Then I get the next error The syntax of the file name, folder name, or volume name is incorrect.(De syntaxis van de bestandsnaam, mapnaam of volumenaam is onjuist.)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.